# Chrome browser is not able to navigate to any site in appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I just installed chrome.apk file in android emulator, and It seems to be installed successfully. But When I tried to execute the below script, Its open up the chrome browser in emulator device but not displayed google home page. And simple the driver is quit.

Sample code: It seems to be launch the browser, but not navigate to google home page

```
public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void initalizeBrowser() throws Exception {
        try {

            DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.android();
            desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,
                    "Android Emulator");
            desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,
                    "4.2.2");
            desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
            desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,
                    "com.android.chrome");
            desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,
                    "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                    new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), desired);
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase1() throws Exception {
        try {

            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        try {
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can somebody assist me what could be the reason for this behavior.

Comment: did you get any exception or error ?

Comment: Yes. I got the below error message in appium server   
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: An error occurred (Original error: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64))) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 354.13 seconds.  But visually I could see the browser was launched but It closed without entering the url into address bar.

Comment: I am not sure if you need to put all those htings like app activity and app package for using chrome

Comment: Can ypu remove them and run. For me this works -  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    //    capabilities.setCapability("avd","firstavd");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "MiPad");
        capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "true");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Comment: @Shamik - Can you tell me the driver is an instance of WebDriver or appiumdriver? Could you please tell me fullReset is required? If its what is the reason? Still I tried to open the chrome browser manually which I installed in emulator, but It opened and closed automatically without throws any error traces. I used chrome 46, and 38 for android api level 17. but none seems to be worked.

Comment: Full reset will reset the application I thnk it cleans caches and cookies and opens an brand new instance no history but you dont need it for this case.

Comment: Okay. But, the problem is while I'm tried to open the installed chrome apk itself within few seconds closed without any exception. what could be a reason for this? It opened but not let me to enter the url by manually.

Comment: I thing their might be some issue with space allocation in emulator device. Might be physical memory is full. that's what its opened but not able to perform. Is there any way to increase the mobile space? is it possible to do it through AVD device manager itself?

Comment: Probably something like that since it crashing manually as well... I am not sure can you search

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this? increase the space?

Comment: No.. have you tried using the inbuilt browser in the image of the emulator

Comment: Can you share me what is inbuild browser in the image? Could you please share the screenshot which is more helpful for me.

Comment: You said you installed chrome right ? But android comes with an inbuilt browser. you can launch that by changing the             desired.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");

check this for more information - http://appium.io/slate/en/1.4/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities

Comment: Go through this once - https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/mobile-web.md Might help

Comment: @Shamik - Its really helpful, and valuable comments. But here the case is failed because of no space in the emulator device. I don't how it could be passed installation if there is no sufficient space in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was also facing the same issue, after a long day search I came to know that the chrome driver need to be in compatible with the chrome browser present in your device. Check the details here:

[Chrome driver for respective browser version](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

After that download the chrome driver which is suitable and replace it with the chrome driver present in the appium installed folder:

```
\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver
```

In my case it is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver
```