# Appium session, could not find a connected Android device. Shows error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium, junit

**Appium session, could not find a connected Android device.  Shows error in eclipse**

If any one know how to fix please let me know.

**The Junit code: - **

```
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

    public class desiredCapab {

        @Test
        public void test() throws MalformedURLException {

            File appDir = new File("C:\\Eclipse-Neon\\Project\\AppiumT\\Apk\\");

                File app = new File (appDir, "WhatsApp.apk");


            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL ("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

            //{"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
        }
    }
```

**Eclipse Junit Error :-**

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 28.61 seconds
Build info: version: '2.49.0', revision: '365eeb4', time: '2016-01-13 18:33:29'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-PC1SJR4', ip: '192.168.1.104', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'

**AVD manager setting: - Image**

[image]

**Appium :- Error message**

```
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\\Eclipse-Neon\\Project\\AppiumT\\Apk\\WhatsApp.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Android Emulator"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_91)
> info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
> info: [debug] No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
> info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\Eclipse-Neon\Project\AppiumT\Apk\WhatsApp.apk
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session c9232f90-f519-4058-9e80-22cd2830de57
> info: Starting android appium
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
> info: Java version is: 1.8.0_101
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\aapt.exe dump badging C:\Eclipse-Neon\Project\AppiumT\Apk\WhatsApp.apk
> info: [debug] badging package: com.whatsapp
> info: [debug] badging act: com.whatsapp.Main
> info: [debug] Parsed package and activity are: com.whatsapp/com.whatsapp.Main
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
> info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
> info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
> info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
> info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
> warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
> info: [debug] Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
>     at [object Object].ADB.getDevicesWithRetry (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:606:15)
>     at [object Object].androidCommon.prepareActiveDevice (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:400:12)
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:326:26)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:607:21
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:17
>     at iterate (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:146:13)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:157:25
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:248:21
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:612:34
>     at [object Object].androidCommon.ensureDeviceLocale (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:371:45)
>     at [object Object].androidCommon.prepareEmulator (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:364:10)
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:325:26)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:607:21
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:17
>     at iterate (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:146:13)
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:157:25
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:248:21
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:612:34
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:344:9)
>     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.)","origValue":"Could not find a connected Android device."},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 28492.200 ms - 206
```

Comment: What helped to me was to replace the old version of chromedriver by the newest one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891287/chrome-browser-is-not-able-to-navigate-to-any-site-in-appium

Answer (score 2):

Reason of above error is, any device or AVD could not be found to be connected. Following lines in your error message show this:

```
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\bizBoxChat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
> info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...

> info: [debug] Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
```

Just creating AVD in AVD manager is not sufficient. It has to be up and running (started and ready). To do that, select any AVD in your AVD manager, and click on "Start" button. Let the AVD boot. Wait. (It is similar to a real device switching on.)
Or, some real device needs to be connected. In that device, "Developer Options" should be On. "USB debugging" should be On.

Go to command prompt and run following command:

```
adb devices
```

Expected output: Some device or AVD should be shown as connected.
Once you see any device or AVD connected, and retry, then your problem will be solved.

Note:
On running "adb devices" command in command window, if you see message like "abd.exe is an unrecognized internal or external command or batch file...", then you need to have adb.exe in path. You can add its path in environment variables, or simply run following command before running "adb devices":

```
set path=%PATH%;"D:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools"
```

Note that adb.exe file is in platform-tools folder on my PC, in Android SDK folder. You will need to modify this path as it is on your PC.

Comment: i tried both. not working   do you have neither idea

Comment: What output did you get when you ran "adb devices" command in command window?

Comment: In my case, the adb devices output displays the device name and I have give the platform tools under PATH.
But still appium cannot find the device

Answer (score 0):

Try to use real device, since emulators are very slow and booting time will also take more time. Even real device also I was facing this kind of issue,

Expecting causes :

1. Android emulator startup issue
2. ADB issue
3. System config

If adb issue, you need run following command in your cmd:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Then you try with Android emulator and make ensure you system has enough memory these emulator like VM this will CPU & memory of your system accountable amount.

Comment: i tried both. not working. do you have a neither idea.